# Errors which I cannot seem to understand in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently writing a code for an app on flutter, however there seems to be an issue, and that is whenever I press the play button, the simulator seems to work fine showing everything I need in the "run" section:

[image]

I assume by the above, that everything seems to be fine. However when I go to the Dart Analysis section, I get these blue exclamation mark errors which I do not know how to fix and they all seem to display the same error:

[image]

My question is can I ignore these errors? If not how do I fix them? Even if I do not fix them, will it bite me later when I am near the completion of the app? Sorry if my questions sound dumb as I am very new to Dart and Flutter. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: IDE is just warning you about a naming convention rule you don't seem to be following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's not error it's a warning. Yes, you can ignore these warnings. `lowerCamelCase` means that names capitalize the first letter of each word, except the first which is always lowercase, even if it’s an acronym. you can refer [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-other-identifiers-using-lowercamelcase).and these are styling warning and it does not affect you later on the production of the app.